# Как закрыть форму после закрытия соединения с sql базой в C#?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Не долго изучаю C#. У меня есть простая программа на C#. В интерфейсе есть кнопка "Выход" в обработчике этой кнопки есть строки описывающие разрыв с базой данных SQL. Ниже хочу добавить строку закрытия формы. Но не знаю как правильно сделать.

```cs
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
    if (sqlConnection != null
        && sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) 
    sqlConnection.Close();
    /*
    Как сюда добавить?
    form1.close(); 
    */
}
```

Что-бы и соединение с базой закрыть и форму ?

Comment: Разберитесь для начала с форматированием кода в вашем вопросе, это же читать невозможно.

Comment: В WPF нету форм, вы точно уверены, что у вас именно указанный тип проекта?

Comment: Для того чтобы закрыть окно = this.close();

Comment: Все получилось, большое спасибо Denis!  this.close(); здесь только this.Close(); надо написать и все программа закрылась.

Comment: Событие `FormClosing` вызывается при закрытии формы. То есть уже происходит то, что вам нужно: форма закрывается.

Comment: Ответьте, наконец, на вопрос: какой у вас тип проекта: WinForms или WPF? И исправьте термины и метки.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void выходToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Обработчик кнопки "Выход" //
{
    if (sqlConnection != null && sqlConnection.State != ConnectionState.Closed) // При нажатии кнопки "Выход" закрываем соединение с базой //
    sqlConnection.Close();     // Собственно эта строка закрывает соединение с базой //
    this.Close(); // Эта команда закрывает форму! //
}
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код!

Comment: `ToolStrip` нету в WPF...